# Menu with table layout in LibGDX won't load

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm using a table layout for my option menu in my game.
But when I launch the screen there's just a black screen.
See yourself :

```
package com.me.mygdxgame;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.CheckBox;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Table;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.ChangeListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.ClickListener;

public class BlueToothOptionScreen implements Screen{

    final Stage stage;
    Skin skin;
    boolean hote = false;
    Table table;

    public BlueToothOptionScreen() {
        System.out.println("Option screen, commencement de l'initialisation");
        this.stage = new Stage(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), true);
        FileHandle skinFile1 = Gdx.files.internal("uiskin.json");
        skin = new Skin(skinFile1);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {

        stage.act(delta);
        Gdx.gl.glClear( GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

        stage.draw();
        Table.drawDebug(stage);
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        stage.setViewport(width, height, true);
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor( stage );

        table = new Table(skin);
        stage.addActor(table);
        table.setFillParent(true);
        table.defaults().spaceBottom(30);
        table.add("Options").colspan(3);

        final CheckBox hoteCheckBox = new CheckBox( "", skin );
        hoteCheckBox.setChecked(true);
        hoteCheckBox.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void changed(
                ChangeEvent event,
                Actor actor )
            {
                boolean enabled = hoteCheckBox.isChecked();
                hote = enabled;
            }
        } );
        table.row();
        table.add("Hote");
        table.add(hoteCheckBox);
        System.out.println("prout");


    }


}
```

I would be glad if you can help me out.
If you need anything else to understand the problem, ask me.

Comment: If you add something other than table (like image or textlabel) to the stage, is it visible?

Comment: @TanmayPatil, No don't work I tried to do this and it's always black
`FileHandle skinFile1 = Gdx.files.internal("uiskin.json");  
  skin = new Skin(skinFile1);  
  Label text = new Label("Text", skin);  
  stage.addActor(text);  
  Gdx.input.setInputProcessor( stage );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem possibly lies with the skin.

Try replacing table with an image, if it works, the problem is definitely with skin.
In this case, consider using correct (tested) skin from libgdx tests.

Make sure you have 5 files (at least) uiskin.json, uiskin.atlas, uiskin.png, default.fnt, default.png (last two correspond to font).

Good luck.